# VS Code going crazy not let me open my projecr

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i open my project through vs code live server it is perfectly fine and when i directly open that same project through html file it is showing with some css missing(Not all css is missing mostly pictures and padding) sorry for my bad english

I don't even know what to try help me out i'm a newbie

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific pls? Mostly it looks like a relative path issue in your CSS and image code. If you can paste your code (part of) it will be helpful. Mainly when you use a live server your HTML is served via that server but when you open the .HTML file directly it is just getting loaded from your filesystem.

The most common mistake is using root in the path. See the following example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

When this is loaded from the live server it is loaded from the sam folder where your .HTML is present because the "root" of the server is that folder but when you open it directly your harddisk's root becomes the root (e.g. in windows c:) and of course, your file is not there.